# how to change the label text present inside a div? and how to change the dropdown to a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, textbox, label

i am having the following html

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_type">Approver</label>
    <select class="form-control appr_type" id="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_type" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][approver_type]" onchange="$.fn.myFunc(this);">
        <option selected="selected" value="Role">Role</option>
        <option value="Specific User">Specific User</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    </br>
</div>
<div class="field" class="role">
    <label for="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_value">Role</label>
    <select class="form-control appr_type" id="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_value" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][approver_value]">
        <option value="hr manager">hr manager</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="reporting manager">reporting manager</option>
    </select>
    <input id="approval_approvers_attributes_0__destroy" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false" /><a class=" remove_nested_fields" data-association="approvers" href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a> 
    </br>
    </br>
</div>
```

and the followng js function definition:

```
$.fn.myFunc = function (button) {    
    var id = $(button).attr('id');
    id = button.id;    
    $(button).next().label.text("specific user");
}
```

the call to this above Jquery function is made in the first div. this function is called when the dropdown in the first div is changed. in this function i want  the label text to be changed to `"specific user"` which is present in the second div, when the user selects  `"specific user"`. and accordingly i want to change the dropdown which is present  in the second div to textbox, to enter the specific user name. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like,

```
<div class="field" class="role">
    <label for="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_value">Role</label>
    <select class="form-control appr_type" id="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_value" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][approver_value]">
        <option value="hr manager">hr manager</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="reporting manager">reporting manager</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="inpt_specific_user" style="display:none"/>
    <input id="approval_approvers_attributes_0__destroy" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false" /><a class=" remove_nested_fields" data-association="approvers" href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a> 
    </br>
    </br>
</div>

<script>
    $.fn.myFunc = function (button) {    
        var id = $(button).attr('id');
        id = button.id;    
        var $nextDiv = $(button).closest('div.field') // get closest parent field
                                .next('div.field') // get next parent field
         $nextDiv.find('label') // find label
                 .text(button.value); //change text, this.value so that it will be dynamic for both the values    
         $nextDiv.find('select.appr_type,input.inpt_specific_user')
                 .toggle(); // toggle select/input =>hide/show

    }
</script>
```

```js
$.fn.myFunc = function(button) {
  var id = $(button).attr('id');
  id = button.id;
  var $nextDiv = $(button).closest('div.field') // get closest parent field
    .next('div.field') // get next parent field
  $nextDiv.find('label') // find label
    .text(button.value); //change text, this.value so that it will be dynamic for both the values    
  $nextDiv.find('select.appr_type,input.inpt_specific_user')
    .toggle(); // toggle select/input =>hide/show

}
$('#approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_type').on('change', function() {

  $.fn.myFunc(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <label for="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_type">Approver</label>
  <select class="form-control appr_type" id="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_type" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][approver_type]" onchange="">
    <option selected="selected" value="Role">Role</option>
    <option value="Specific User">Specific User</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  </br>
</div>
<div class="field" class="role">
  <label for="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_value">Role</label>
  <select class="form-control appr_type" id="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_value" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][approver_value]">
    <option value="hr manager">hr manager</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="reporting manager">reporting manager</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="inpt_specific_user" style="display:none" />
  <input id="approval_approvers_attributes_0__destroy" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false" /><a class=" remove_nested_fields" data-association="approvers" href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a> 
  </br>
  </br>
</div>
```

Updated, code without using extra element and using [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith)

```js
$.fn.myFunc = function(button) {
  var id = $(button).attr('id');
  id = button.id;
  var $nextDiv = $(button).closest('div.field') // get closest parent field
    .next('div.field') // get next parent field
  $nextDiv.find('label') // find label
    .text(button.value); //change text, this.value so that it will be dynamic for both the values
  var $el = null;
  if (button.value != 'Role') {
    $nextDiv.find('select.appr_type').replaceWith('<input type="text" class="form-control appr_type" id="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_value" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][approver_value]"  />');
  } else {
    $nextDiv.find('input.appr_type').replaceWith('<select class="form-control appr_type" id="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_value" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][approver_value]">\
        <option value="hr manager">hr manager</option>\
        <option selected="selected" value="reporting manager">reporting manager</option>\
    </select>');
  }
}
$('#approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_type').on('change', function() {
  $.fn.myFunc(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <label for="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_type">Approver</label>
  <select class="form-control appr_type" id="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_type" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][approver_type]" onchange="">
    <option selected="selected" value="Role">Role</option>
    <option value="Specific User">Specific User</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  </br>
</div>
<div class="field" class="role">
  <label for="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_value">Role</label>
  <select class="form-control appr_type" id="approval_approvers_attributes_0_approver_value" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][approver_value]">
    <option value="hr manager">hr manager</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="reporting manager">reporting manager</option>
  </select>

  <input id="approval_approvers_attributes_0__destroy" name="approval[approvers_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false" /><a class=" remove_nested_fields" data-association="approvers" href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a> 
  </br>
  </br>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the immediate response. how to change the dropdown to text box when the user selects "specific user". and after selecting specific user again if he changes his choice to role in that case how to change this "text box" to the "dropdown" again?

Comment: the function is not working. the label text is not changing.

Comment: but i cant use the another input field, why because this html is getting  generated by the nested form gem in rails. i cant give class and i cant hide it initially.  even if i give all this  fields will contain the same class. i mean this is the markup for one approver entry. like this there may be any number of approvers may be present.  if there are 10 approvers this markup will repeat 10 times. so i want to change the drop down to text box

Comment: sorry for that it was  clicked unexpectedly .

Comment: Check my updated answer and FYI...By clicking again on the same it will undone the down-vote.